# What contributes to DailyDurableStreamingApiEvents Limit

Tags: governorlimits, limits

We appear to be using a high % of the limit of **DailyDurableStreamingApiEvents**.

What is this Salesforce limit and what sort of things contribute towards it?
(Do normal Platform Event triggers contribute towards this limit?)

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: The limit is for Streaming API (PushTopic et al), it is not for Platform Events - see linked answer for details.